# How to Bind to a Custom Template within a Custom bindingHandler in Knockout

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I am in the need to generate a Bootstrap Popover.  I have found an article or two but they do not seem to work 100% within my situation.  I can get the Popover to display, however the bindings within the template are not getting bound.

Here is my custom `bindingHandler`:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.popover = {
  init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    var $element = $(element);
    var attribute = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
    var placement = attribute.placement || "top";
    var trigger = attribute.trigger || "click";
    var template = attribute.template;
    var container = attribute.container || false;
    var boundTemplate = $(template).html();

    $element.popover({
      container: container,
      placement: placement,
      trigger: trigger,
      html: true,
      content: boundTemplate
    });

    ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
      $element.popover("destroy");
    });
  }
};
```

The `html` is within a `table`'s  `td` node, thus within the binding I allow the `container` to be passed in as `body` seeing that Bootstrap needs this for Popovers within a Table:

```
<span class="bottom-right faded"
      data-toggle="popover"
      title="Weekly Breakdown:"
      data-trigger="hover"
      data-bind="text: Number(PayPeriodTime()).toFixed(2), css: { 'less-hours': HasRequiredHours() === false, 'requirement-met': (HasRequiredHours() && WorkDays() > 0) }, popover: { template: '#weekly-template', placement: 'left', container: 'body', trigger: 'hover' }"></span>
```

Lastly, here is my custom template:

```
<script type="text/html" id="weekly-template">
  <pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data, null, 2)"></pre>
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
      <td>Full Weeks Hours</td>
      <td data-bind="text: Number(TotalTime()).toFixed(2)">5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Required Hours</td>
      <td data-bind="text: Number(RequiredHours()).toFixed(2)"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Entered Hours</td>
      <td data-bind="text: Number(PayPeriodTime()).toFixed(2)"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Remaining Needed</td>
      <td data-bind="text: Number(RequiredHours() - PayPeriodTime()).toFixed(2)"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</script>
```

The `pre` element is empty seemingly with no matter what I put in there.  When the popup shows up upon `hover` it renders the html but none of my ko items.  All I see is the `5` that I force in for the `Full Weeks Hours` just to see that something gets in there.

The `boundTemplate` variable within the binding has the full html and ko code within in.  I just seem to need to run that through some sort of processing method that will turn `Number(TotalTime()).toFixed(2)` into some value before it gets put into the popover as `content: boundTemplate`.

Comment: Please post the correct answer, and mark that answer as accepted.

Comment: @NisargShah I have moved my solution to an answer.  In 2 days (when I am allowed) I will mark it as the answer.

Comment: Great. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After speaking with a coworker, this is the solution (note the comments prefixed with //):

```
ko.bindingHandlers.popover = {
  init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    var $element = $(element);
    var attribute = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
    var placement = attribute.placement || "top";
    var trigger = attribute.trigger || "click";
    var template = attribute.template;
    var container = attribute.container || false;

    var rawTemplate = $(template).html(); // Updated code
    var boundContent = $("<div></div>"); // New code
    boundContent.html(rawTemplate); // New code

    ko.applyBindings(bindingContext, boundContent.get(0)); // New code

    $element.popover({
      container: container,
      placement: placement,
      title: title,
      trigger: trigger,
      html: true,
      content: boundContent // Updated code
    });

    ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
      $element.popover("destroy");
    });
  }
};
```